# git gui - in which file is the [tmp] commit message stored?

Tags: git, git-gui

When I fire up git gui I see the last commit message I wrote - sometimes I loose it (for instance when I hit amend commit too hurriedly). I mostly work in Dropbox however so I am able to rollback (or examine) files there. So in which file is the commit message stored ? Is it in `.git` or someplace else ?

I am on windows (7 or XP depends) - hopefully this is system independent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git-gui` creates a `.git/GITGUI_BCK` temp file to store the commit message **as you're editing it**.

If you close `git-gui` **without committing**, the commit message will be moved to `.git/GITGUI_MSG`.

The temp files is removed after committing.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D found this through pure experimentation :) there doesn't seem to be any official resource referencing this (at least nothing a few brief google searches revealed), though I'm sure it's documented somewhere. I'll update the answer if I ever find it

Comment: Git is open source, so it’s documented where everything else is – in the code :). https://github.com/git/git/search?q=GITGUI_MSG&ref=cmdform

Comment: @Chronial yep, always look at the sourcecode. good info, thanks

Comment: @Chronial : well yes - but you wouldn't know what to look for in the first place - a user manual helps (read is needed) at times

Comment: There is a reason why there is a smiley in my comment ;). Of course this stuff should be documented in a manual, but matter of fact is that this is almost never true for open source software. While this is certainly not perfect it also just a fact of life that you have to accept ^^.